# .NET 8 Blazor Interactive Server. Where to store JWT tokens?

Tags: asp.net, blazor-server-side, .net-8.0

I~ve overriden AutnenticationStateProvider with a custom one. When entering my application, GetAuthenticationStateAsync method is being called. In the method, there is a local storage request to get the JWT.

```
public class SmartRecipesAuthenticationStateProvider : AuthenticationStateProvider
{
    private readonly HttpClient httpClient;
    private readonly ILocalStorageService localStorage;

    public SmartRecipesAuthenticationStateProvider(HttpClient httpClient, ILocalStorageService localStorage)
    {
        this.httpClient = httpClient;
        this.localStorage = localStorage;
    }

    private byte[] ParseBase64WithoutPadding(string base64)
    {
        switch (base64.Length % 4) {
            case 2: base64 += "=="; break;
            case 3: base64 += "="; break;
        }
        return Convert.FromBase64String(base64);
    }

    private List<Claim> ParseClaimFromJwt(string jwt)
    {
        List<Claim> claims = new();
        var payload = jwt.Split(".")[1];
        var jsobBytes = ParseBase64WithoutPadding(payload);
        var keyValuePairs = JsonSerializer.Deserialize<Dictionary<string, object>>(jsobBytes);

        keyValuePairs!.TryGetValue(ClaimTypes.Role, out object? roles);

        if (roles is not null)
        {
            if (roles.ToString()!.Trim().StartsWith("["))
            {
                var parsedRoles = JsonSerializer.Deserialize<string[]>(roles.ToString()!);
                foreach (var role in parsedRoles!)
                {
                    claims.Add(new Claim(ClaimTypes.Role, role));
                }
            }
            else
            {
                claims.Add(new Claim(ClaimTypes.Role, roles.ToString()!));
            }
            keyValuePairs.Remove(ClaimTypes.Role);
        }
        claims.AddRange(keyValuePairs.Select(x => new Claim(x.Key, x.Value.ToString()!)));

        return claims;
    }

    public override async Task<AuthenticationState> GetAuthenticationStateAsync()
    {
        var savedToken = await localStorage.GetItemAsync<string>("authToken");

        if (string.IsNullOrEmpty(savedToken))
        {
            return new AuthenticationState(new ClaimsPrincipal(new ClaimsIdentity()));
        }

        httpClient.DefaultRequestHeaders.Authorization = new AuthenticationHeaderValue("bearer", savedToken);
        return new AuthenticationState(new ClaimsPrincipal(new ClaimsIdentity(ParseClaimFromJwt(savedToken), "jwt")));
    }

    public void MarkUserAsLoggedIn(string email)
    {
        var authenticatedUser = new ClaimsPrincipal(new ClaimsIdentity(new[] { new Claim(ClaimTypes.Email, email) }, "apiauth"));
        var authState = Task.FromResult(new AuthenticationState(authenticatedUser));
        NotifyAuthenticationStateChanged(authState);
    }

    public void MarkUserAsLoggedOut()
    {
        var anonymousUser = new ClaimsPrincipal(new ClaimsIdentity());
        var authState = Task.FromResult(new AuthenticationState(anonymousUser));
        NotifyAuthenticationStateChanged(authState);
    }
}
```

**Program:**

```
services
.AddAuthentication(JwtBearerDefaults.AuthenticationScheme)
.AddJwtBearer(options =>
{
    options.TokenValidationParameters = new()
    {
        ValidateIssuer = true,
        ValidateAudience = true,
        ValidateLifetime = true,
        ValidateIssuerSigningKey = true,
        ValidIssuer = config["JWTIssuer"],
        ValidAudience = config["JWTAudience"],
        IssuerSigningKey = new SymmetricSecurityKey(Encoding.UTF8.GetBytes(config["JWTSecurityKey"]!))
    };
});

services.AddAuthorization();
services.AddScoped<AuthenticationStateProvider, SmartRecipesAuthenticationStateProvider>();
```

This approach produces JSInterop exception because of local storage:
InvalidOperationException: JavaScript interop calls cannot be issued at this time. This is because the component is being statically rendered. When prerendering is enabled, JavaScript interop calls can only be performed during the OnAfterRenderAsync lifecycle method.

Seems like, auth state check is being made in OnInitialized method, not in OnAfterRender as makers suggest.

I still want to store JWT tokens somewhere client-side**. Is there a way to implement it?

**Because I dont want users to login each time they re-visit my app

Comment: "if your app is using a sign in scenario that doesn't require API calls, only an ID token is required. There is no need to store it. You can validate it and get the data from it that you required.

If your app needs to call APIs on behalf of the user, access tokens and (optionally) refresh tokens are needed. These can be stored server-side or in a session cookie. " - REF 

https://auth0.com/docs/secure/security-guidance/data-security/token-storage#don-t-store-tokens-in-local-storage

Comment: @AdamVincent Is it okay to store tokens in Http request headers?

Comment: HTTP headers are not storage. You would be openly passing around tokens. So not likely safe to do so, seems vulnerable to a MITM (man-in-the-middle) attack. I'm not a security expert though, which is why I stick to the recommendations.